# I am trying to create an expression that will extract URLs

Tags: regex, url, extract

I want to extract URLs from a webpage these are just URLs by themselves not hyperlinks etc., they are just text. Some examples would be `http://www.example.com`, `http://example.com`, `www.example.com` etc. I am extremely new at regex so I have copy and pasted like 20 expressions online all failed to work. I don't know if I am doing it right or not. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Regex buddy ( http://www.regexbuddy.com/ ) and the regex cheatsheet ( http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ )are your friends...

Comment: what language are you using to attempt extracting the URLs, and how are you going about it? An example of what regular expressions you're using and how you're running them would help.

Comment: iam very new to this but i think its .net that the software is running in and what i did is teh software extracts the entire content than you use regex to further refine your selection...i want to extract a website url there's sometimes 10 of them in the selection sometimes none sometimes 100 i just want one doesn't matter which one..the only regex iam using is ones i find online i dotn even know if iam implemeting them right...i ahev succesfully got regex to work to get email and phone numbers but can get it to get urls nevermind just one url out of the selction..

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not escaping your `.`s. You need to use `\.` for each one.

Take a look at [strfriend.com](http://strfriend.com/). It has a URL example, and represents it graphically.

The example it suggests is:

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)://|~/|/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w-]+.)+(\w{2,5}))(:\d{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+.\w{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?
```

Comment: (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?

this worked

Comment: Sorry, your code worked, or mine? Also, why are you searching for `&amp;`? Are you searching an XML document for URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post on using Regex to locate links within a HTML page (the intent was to use JavaScript to open external links or links to documents such as PDF's etc in a popup window).

The final regex was:
^(?:[./]+)?(?:Assets|https?://(?!(?:www.)?integralist))

The full post is here:
http://www.integralist.co.uk/javascript/regular-expression-to-open-external-links-in-popup-window/

The solution wont be perfect but might help point you in the right direction.

Mark